# Ruby: Rubeque: Variable in regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex, string-interpolation

I'm solving http://www.rubeque.com/problems/a-man-comma--a-plan-comma--a-canal--panama-excl-/solutions but I'm a bit confused about treating #{} as comment in regexp.
My code look like this now

```
def longest_palindrome(txt)
  txt[/#{txt.reverse}/]
end
```

I tried `txt[/"#{txt.reverse}"/]` or `txt[#{txt.reverse}]` but nothing works as I wish. How should I implicate variable into regexp?

Comment: You had it right the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can do with a regex.

While you could use variable interpolation in the construction of a regex (see the other answers/comments), that wouldn't help you here. You could only use that to reverse a literal string, not a regex match result. Even if you could, you still wouldn't have solved the "find the longest palindrome" part, at least not with acceptable runtime performance.

Use a different approach to the problem.

Comment: This is wrong, variable interpolation works just fine in a `//` regex literal: `/#{1 + 2}/ #=> /3/`.

Comment: @Andrew Interesting, thanks. So the OP's code was in fact valid Ruby (regardless of the fact that it doesn't work as intended)?

Comment: Yes. It’s also worth noting that nothing in the interpolated text is escaped to be treated as regular text (i.e. `/#{'.*'}/ =~ 'foo'` is truthy).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell how do you wish that happens without examples, but I suppose you are after

```
txt[/#{Regexp.escape(txt.reverse)}/]
```

See the [Regexp#escape](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) method

Comment: there is link to rubeque with asserts

Comment: I don't think that's his actual problem. He wants to find the longest palindrome in a string. Definitely not a regular language.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Modern regexes aren't exactly regular either.

Comment: @FilipBartuzi ups, sorry for missing the link. Anyway you got your answer :-)

Comment: Those quotes don't belong there though